# React input mask focus position moved to end when use with redux component rerender

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am using [this](https://github.com/sanniassin/react-input-mask) mask component in my app. Component value is coming from redux. In the OnChange event I dispatched the action and value gets updated. Issue is that this component focus move to end when ever I type and component rerenders. Is this the default behavior or their is a bug in it. Need help

[image: demo]

Comment: that is not the default behavior.  can you show the code?  and try to show what is being set in the store?

Comment: I use redux hook useSelector,useDispatch to pick up state and dispatching action